# Released Microphone when other application need to use

Tags: android, service, microphone

I am making an application which uses microphone in background service. i am recording continuously in my application using service. if i open other application(Use microphone) just like video recording, google voice then i get error microphone use by other app that time i want to released microphone from my services.

I use following permission in my application

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

also write one services in this services i start recording.

Please help me....
other wise please suggest me any options

Comment: I don't think there is any API to do that.  I suspect Google is cheating and just giving the microphone to its voice app whenever nobody else owns it.